# how to replace " char to '?

Tags: javascript

i want to replace a `"` char with `'`.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`replace` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on the string `str` you want to replace it in:

```
str = str.replace(/"/g, "'");
```

Important is to use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with the *g* flag set to replace globally. If you omit that *g* flag or use a string for the search, you will only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: @Kerberos: You’re welcome! And don’t forget to accept an answer (this does also apply to your other questions).

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace("\"", "\'")
```

Comment: That will only replace the first double quote.

Comment: I did not know he needed to do more then that. :-(

Comment: I don't know either, but it seems a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method:

```
str = str.replace(/"/g, "'"));
```

Comment: Why the *i* flag? What is the uppercase/lowercase variant of `"`? ;-)